# Two definitions of Lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Normally, Lebesgue integral, for positive measures, is defined in the following way. First, one defines the integral for indicator functions, and linearly extend to simple functions. Then, for a general non-negative function $f$ , it is defined as the supremum of the integral of all simple functions less than or equal $f$.

However, I find another definition in the book of Lieb and Loss, "Analysis". Let $f$ be the non-negative measurable function on a measure space $X$, let $\mu$ be the measure, and define for $t >0$,
$$S_f(t) = \{x \in X : f(x) >t\},$$
and
$$F_f(t) = \mu(S_f(t)) .$$

Note that $F_f(t)$ is now a Riemann integrable function. Now, the Lebesgue integral is defined as:

$$ \int_X f \, d\mu = \int_0^\infty F_f(t) \, dt,$$

where the integral on the right-hand side is the Riemann integral.

[Here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=S-CGnXWy0HcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q&f=false) is the google books link to the definition.

The book gives a heuristic reason why this definition agrees with the usual definition described here in the first paragraph. Now I would like to have a rigorous proof of the equivalence.

Comment: It follows from Fubini's theorem.

Comment: This fact is sketched for probability measure $\mu$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition) - the last formula. I wouldn't take it as a definition, though - just as a useful fact. As a definition it seems to be too hard to work with, e.g. linearity in the argument $f$ is not that easy to see.

Comment: This formula has no reason to be true if the underlying measure isn't $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Siminore: Maybe it is true by Fubini. Then could you please complete the proof by proving that the Riemann integral of the Riemann-integrable functions agree with this definition? Whichever way you go, I would like a complete proof, please.

Comment: @Ahriman : Counterexample, please.

Comment: Why, are you doubting what Ahriman said?

Comment: @timur: Indeed. Else, I would be a mere Thomas.

Comment: @Ahriman: The formula is true for an arbitrary measure space (when the right hand side is interpreted as a Lebesgue integral and $F_f(t)$ is replaced by the outer measure $F_f(t) = \mu^\ast(S_f(t))$ and holds as stated  if $\mu$ is complete). No need to assume $\sigma$-finiteness or anything else on $\mu$. This is proved e.g. in Fremlin's [measure theory](http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm), volume 2, 252 O.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: This definition seems to be a bit more intuitive in my opinion. Thank you for shareing.

Answer (score 20):

I'll paraphrase the slicing argument given in Fremlin's *[Measure theory](http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm)*, Volume 2, **252O**, page 220. Since I'm not going to base a theory of integration on this formula, I think it's legitimate to appeal to (very) basic Lebesgue theory (no Fubini, only monotone convergence) to prove the desired identity. I leave it to you to deal with the necessary but easy modifications if you allow extended real-valued functions or partially defined functions:

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f\colon X \to [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function. Then for the usual Lebesgue integral $\int_X f\,d\mu$ of $f$ over $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ we have the identity
>   $$
> \int_X f\,d\mu = \int_{0}^\infty \mu\{x\in X\,:\,f(x) \gt t\}\,dt
> $$
>   where the second integral is a Lebesgue integral of a non-increasing and non-negative function, hence the integrand is continuous up to a countable subset of $[0,\infty)$, and thus its Riemann integral exists in the extended sense and the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide for it.

To prove this, set $E^{n}_k = \left\{x \in X\,:\,f(x) \gt \frac{k}{2^{n}}\right\}$ and put
$$
g_n = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=1}^{4^n} [E_{k}^n]
$$
where $[A]$ denotes the characteristic function of $A$. Note that we have $0 \leq f(x) - g_n(x) \lt 2^{-n}$ whenever $0 \leq f(x) \lt 2^n$, so that $g_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in X$. Also, $g_n(x) \leq g_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x$, so the sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ increases to $f$ pointwise everywhere. By the monotone convergence theorem we conclude that
$$\tag{1}
\int_X f\,d\mu = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_X g_n\,d\mu.
$$
Moreover, for every $t \in [0,\infty)$, we have
$$
\{x\in X\,:\,f(x) \gt t\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{x \in X\,:\,g_n(x) \gt t\},
$$
so, using the notation in the question, we have for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ that
$$
F_f(t) = 
\mu\{x\in X\,:\,f(x) \gt t\} = 
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu\{x \in X\,:\,g_n(x) \gt t\} 
= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} F_{g_n}(t)
$$
where the convergence is monotone in $n$. Again by the monotone convergence theorem we get
$$\tag{2}
\int_{0}^\infty \mu\{x\in X\,:\,f(x) \gt t\}\,dt = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^\infty \mu\{x \in X\,:\,g_n(x) \gt t\}\,dt.
$$
Recalling the definitions of $E_{k}^n$ and $g_n$ we see that
$$
\mu E_{k}^n =
\begin{cases} 
  \mu\{x\in X\,:\,g_n(x) \gt t\}
    & \text{if }1 \leq k \leq 4^n
      \text{ and }
      \frac{k-1}{2^n} \leq t \lt \frac{k}{2^n}
    \\
  0,
    & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$ 
so that
$$\tag{3}
\int_{0}^\infty \mu\{x\in X\,:\,g_n(x) \gt t\}\,dt =  
\sum_{k=1}^{4^n} \frac{1}{2^n}\mu E_{k}^n = 
\int_{X} g_n\,d\mu.
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ using $(3)$ we get the desired formula
$$
\int_X f\,d\mu = \int_{0}^\infty \mu\{x\in X\,:\,f(x) \gt t\}\,dt.
$$

Comment: ...and that's the origin of the expression "Easy as 1,2,3".

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why the RHS is Riemann integrable? $F_f(t)$ can be infinite at some point. What if $\int_Xfd\mu=\infty$?

Answer (score 4):

**Notations and Definitions**
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function on $X$.
We define a function $F_f\colon [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ by

$F_f(t) = \mu(\{x \in X; f(x) > t\})$

We use the definitions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188214/extended-riemann-integrability-of-a-non-negative-function-implies-lebesgue-inte-inte).

**Lemma 1**
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function on $X$.
Suppose $f$ is integrable on $X$.
Then $F_f(t) < \infty$ for every $t > 0$.

Proof:
Let $X_t = \{x \in X; f(x) > t\}$.

Then

$t\mu(X_t) \le \int_{X_t} f \, d\mu \le \int_X f \, d\mu < \infty$.

Since $t > 0$, $F_f(t) = \mu(X_t) < \infty$.

**QED**

**Lemma 2**
Let $[a, b]$ be a finite interval of the real line.
Let $f\colon [a, b] \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty)$ be a monotone function on $[a, b]$.
Then $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Proof:
Without loss of generality, we can assume that $f$ is non-decreasing.
Let $P\colon a = t_0 < t_1 <\cdots < t_{k-1} < t_k = b$ be a partition of $[a, b]$.

Then

$s_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k f(t_{i-1}) (t_i - t_{i-1})$.

$S_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k f(t_i) (t_i - t_{i-1})$.

Hence

$S_P - s_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k (f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})) (t_i - t_{i-1})$

Let $\delta = \max\{t_i - t_{i-1}; i = 1,\dots,k\}$.

Then

$S_P - s_P \le \delta\sum_{i= 1}^k (f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})) = \delta (f(b) - f(a))$

Hence $S_P - s_P$ can be arbitrarily small.

Let $\Phi$ be the set of partitions of $[a, b]$.

Let $s = \sup\{s_P; P \in \Phi\}$.

Let $S = \inf\{S_P; P \in \Phi\}$.

It is easy to see that $s \le S$.
Since $s_P \le s \le S \le S_P$, $s = S$.
Hence $f$ is Riemann integrable.
**QED**

**Lemma 3**
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Suppose $\mu(X) < \infty$.
Let $f$ be a measurable function on $X$.
Suppose $0 \le f(x) \le M$ for every $x \in X$, where $0 < M < \infty$.
Let $P\colon 0 = t_0 < t_1 <\cdots < t_{k-1} < t_k = M$ be a partition of $[0, M]$

Let $m_i = \inf\{F_{f}(x); x \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]\}$.

Let $M_i = \sup\{F_{f}(x); x \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]\}$.

Let $s_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k m_i (t_i - t_{i-1})$.

Let $S_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k M_i (t_i - t_{i-1})$.

Let $A_i = \{x \in X; t_{i-1} < f(x) \le t_i\}$.

Then

$S_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k \mu(A_i)t_i$.

$s_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k \mu(A_i)t_{i-1}$.

Proof:
Note that $F_f(t)$ is a monotone non-increasing function and $F_f(M) = 0$.
Hence for $i = 1,2,\dots k$,

$M_i = F_f(t_{i-1})$

$m_i = F_f(t_i)$

Hence

$S_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k F_f(t_{i-1})(t_i - t_{i-1})$

$s_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k F_f(t_i)(t_i - t_{i-1})$

$S_P = F_f(t_0)t_0 + (F_f(t_0) - F_f(t_1))t_1 + \cdots + (F_f(t_{k-2}) - F_f(t_{k-1}))t_{k-1} + F_f(t_{k-1})t_k = (F_f(t_0) - F_f(t_1))t_1 + \cdots + (F_f(t_{k-2}) - F_f(t_{k-1}))t_{k-1} + (F_f(t_{k-1}) - F_f(t_k))t_k = \sum_{i= 1}^k (F_f(t_{i-1}) - F_f(t_i))t_i = \sum_{i= 1}^k \mu(A_i)t_i$

Similarly

$s_P = \sum_{i= 1}^k \mu(A_i)t_{i-1}$
**QED**

**Lemma 4**
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Suppose $\mu(X) < \infty$.
Let $f$ be a measurable function on $X$.
Suppose $0 \le f(x) \le M$ for every $x \in X$, where $0 < M < \infty$.

Then $F_f$ is Riemann integrable and $\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, M]) = \int_X f \, d\mu$.

Proof:
This is clear from Lemma 3 and [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188176/yet-another-definition-of-lebesgue-integral).

**Lemma 5**
Let $[a, \infty)$ be an infinite interval of the real line, where $-\infty < a < \infty$.
Let $f_n\colon [a, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be a real valued function for $n = 1, 2, \dots$.Suppose $f_n \le f_{n+1} (n = 1,2,\dots)$.
Suppose each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable on every finite interval $[x, y]$, where $a < x < y < \infty$.
Let $f = \lim_n f_n$.
Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on every finite interval $[x, y]$, where $a < x < y < \infty$.

Then $\lim_n \mathcal{R}(f_n, [a, \infty)) = \mathcal{R}(f, [a, \infty))$.

Proof:
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188214/extended-riemann-integrability-of-a-non-negative-function-implies-lebesgue-inte-inte), each $f_n$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\mathcal{R}(f_n, [a, \infty)) = \int_{a}^{\infty} f_n dt$.
By Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem, $\lim_n \mathcal{R}(f_n, [a, \infty)) = \int_{a}^{\infty} f \, dt$.

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188214/extended-riemann-integrability-of-a-non-negative-function-implies-lebesgue-inte-inte), $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\mathcal{R}(f, [a, \infty)) = \int_{a}^\infty f \, dt$.

This completes the proof.
**QED**

**Lemma 5.5**
Let $[a, \infty)$ be an infinite interval of the real line, where $-\infty < a < \infty$.
Let $f\colon [a, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a non-increasing function.
Suppose $f$ is extended Riemann integrable(see Notations and Definitions).
Then $f(t)$ is finite for every $t > a$.

Proof:
Suppose $f(t_0) = \infty$ for some $t_0 > a$.
Since $f$ is non-increasing, $f(t) = \infty$ on $[a, t_0]$.
Hence $\mathcal{R}(f, [a, t_0]) = \infty$.
This is a contradiction.
**QED**

**Lemma 6**
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $f$ be a measurable function on $X$.
Suppose $0 \le f(x) \le M$ for every $x \in X$, where $0 < M < \infty$.

Then $F_f$ is extended Riemann integrable if and only if $f$ is integrable.
Moreover, if this is the case, $\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, M]) = \int_X f \, d\mu$.

Proof:
For every integer $n \ge 1$, let $X_n = \{x \in X; f(x) > 1/n\}$.
Let $f_{n}$ be the function defined on $X$ which is equal to $f$ on $X_n$ and is equal to $0$ outside $X_n$.
Then $f_{n} \le f_{n+1}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$ and $f = \lim_n f_{n}$.

Suppose $F_f$ is extended Riemann integrable.
Since $F_f$ is non-increasing, by Lemma 5.5, $\mu(X_n) < \infty$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$.
Since $F_{f_{n}}$ is non-increasing and bounded, $F_{f_{n}}$ is Riemann integrable on $X$ by Lemma 2. Hence

$\mathcal{R}(F_{f_{n}}, [0, M]) = \int_{X_n} f_n d\mu = \int_X f_n d\mu$ by Lemma 4.
Hence

$\lim_n \mathcal{R}(F_{f_{n}}, [0, M]) = \lim_n \int_X f_n d\mu$

We evaluate the both sides of this equation.

LHS = $\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, \infty))$ by Lemma 5.

RHS = $\lim_n \int_X f \, d\mu$ by Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem.
Hence

$\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, \infty)) = \int_X f \, d\mu$

Hence $f$ is integrable on $X$.

Conversely suppose $f$ is integrable on $X$.
By Lemma 1, $\mu(X_n) < \infty$ for $n = 1,2,\dots$.
Hence $F_{f_n}$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, M]$ and $\mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, M]) = \int_{X_n} f_n d\mu$ by Lemma 4.
By the similar argument as above, $\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, M]) = \int_X f \, d\mu$.
Hence $F_f$ is extended Riemann integrable on $[0, M]$.
**QED**

**Lemma 7**
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $f_n\colon X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a real valued measurable function for $n = 1, 2, \dots$
Suppose $f_n \le f_{n+1}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$
Let $f = \lim_n f_n$.
Then

$F_{f_n} \le F_{f_{n+1}}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$

and

$F_f = \lim_n F_{f_n}$ on $[0, \infty)$.

Proof:
Since $f_n \le f_{n+1}$, $\{x \in X : f_n(x) > t\} \subset \{x \in X : f_{n+1}(x) > t\}$.
Hence $F_{f_n} \le F_{f_{n+1}}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$
Since $\{x \in X : f(x) > t\} = \bigcup_n \{x \in X : f_n(x) > t\}$,
$F_f = \lim_n F_{f_n}$ on $[0, \infty)$.
**QED**

**Proposition**
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function on $X$.
Then $F_f$ is extended Riemann integrable on $[0, \infty)$ if and only if $f$ is integrable on $X$.
If this is the case, $\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, \infty)) = \int_X f \, d\mu$.

Proof:
Suppose $F_f$ is extended Riemann integrable on $[0, \infty)$.
Let $f_n(x) = \min\{f(x), n\}(n = 1,2,\dots)$.
Then $f_n$ is bounded and $f_n \le f_{n+1} (n = 1,2,\dots)$ and $f = \lim_n f_n$.
Since $F_f$ is extended Riemann integrable, each $F_{f_n}$ is extended Riemann integrable.

By Lemma 6, $f_n$ is integrable and $\mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, n]) = \int_X f_n d\mu$.

Since $\mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, n]) = \mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, \infty))$,

$\lim_n \mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, \infty)) = \lim_n \int_X f_n d\mu$.

We evaluate the both sides of this equation.

By Lemma 7, $F_{f_n} \le F_{f_{n+1}}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$
and $F_f = \lim_n F_{f_n}$.

Hence, by Lemma 5, $\lim_n \mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, \infty)) = \mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, \infty))$.

On the other hand, by Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem,

$\lim_n \int_X f_n d\mu = \int_X f \, d\mu$

Hence $\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, \infty)) = \int_X f \, d\mu$.

Conversely suppose $f$ is integrable on $X$.
Let $f_n(x) = \min\{f(x), n\}(n = 1,2,\dots)$.
Then $f_n$ is bounded and $f_n \le f_{n+1} (n = 1,2,\dots)$ and $f = \lim_n f_n$.
Since each $f_n$ is integrable, by Lemma 6,
$F_{f_n}$ is extended Riemann integrable and $\mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, n]) = \int_X f_n d\mu$.

By Lemma 7, $F_{f_n} \le F_{f_{n+1}}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$
and $F_f = \lim_n F_{f_n}$.
Hence, by Lemma 5, $\lim_n \mathcal{R}(F_{f_n}, [0, \infty)) = \mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, \infty))$.
On the other hand, by Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem,

$\lim_n \int_X f_n d\mu = \int_X f \, d\mu$

Hence $\mathcal{R}(F_f, [0, \infty)) = \int_X f \, d\mu$.
**QED**

Comment: @MichaelHardy please edit correctly.

Comment: Please leave a comment explaining the downvote so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: What is it that you object to about the edits I did?

Comment: BTW, I agree with you that those who down-vote postings should explain their objections.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You did not edit "Notations and Definitions" correctly. Please see the edit history. Anyway, thanks for the other edits.