# Additivity of integral, with a different definition of Lebesgue integration

Tags: measure-theory

I noted a definition of Lebesgue integral [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185937/two-definitions-of-lebesgue-integration).

This might be masochism; but how would one prove additivity? This is an "exercise for the reader" in the book of Lieb and Loss, "Analysis".

Comment: If you already have the monotone convergence theorem then the proof is the same.

Comment: @Tim Duff : You would then have to prove equivalence with the definition using simple functions, won't you?

Comment: That's directly computable from the definition you're using.