# Alternate definition of Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm am essentially reasking this question [Two definitions of Lebesgue integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185937/two-definitions-of-lebesgue-integration) but for a different approach.

The answer given is intuitive, however I wondering how exactly to show the equality by using Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_X f(x)\,d\mu=\int _X\int_0^\infty1_{t<f(x)}\,dt\,d\mu=\int_0^\infty\int_X 1_{t<f(x)}\,d\mu\,dt=\int_0^\infty \mu(\{x:f(x)>t\})\,dt$$
The first equality follows since $1_{t<f(x)}$ is $1$ in the interval $[0,f(x)]$, zero elsewhere, so its integral is $f(x)$. The second is of course Fubini-Tonelli, and the third follows from the usual definition of integration.

Is this what you were looking for?