# Definition of Lebesgue integral via improper Riemann integral.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

In the textbook *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss, the Lebesgue integral of a non-negative measurable function is defined as follows:

> \begin{equation} \tag{1}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \: \mathrm{d}x := \int_{0}^{\infty} F_f(t) \: \mathrm{d}t,
> \end{equation}
>   where $ \mathrm{d}x $ is the Lebesgue measure and $ F_f(t) := m(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \: f(x) > t\}) $. So $ F_f(t) $ is a mapping from $ \mathbb{R}^+ $ to $ \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{\infty\}$.

[N.B. I replaced the more general $ \Omega $ by $ \mathbb{R}^n $ and the general measure $ \mu(\mathrm{d}x) $ by the Lebesgue measure.]

**Question 1:** Now, my first question is whether (1) is to mean in detail that
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \: \mathrm{d}x := \lim_{a \to 0} \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} F_f(t) \: \mathrm{d}t,
\end{equation}
since for a non-negative $ L^p $ function $ F_f(0) $ may well be equal to $ \infty $.

It also seems to me that we need both these limits (not only $ b \to \infty $, but also $ a \to 0 $) to make use of the fact that monotone functions (and $ F_f(0) $ is clearly one of them) are Riemann integrable on closed intervals.

**Question 2:** But then, how can we be sure that the double limit on the right side in (2) exists, i.e. that it takes a finite number or converges to $ \infty $. That is, how to be sure that the Riemann integral on the right side in (1) exists in the extended sense?

Any hints, suggestions or answers (as well as references to textbooks) would be much appreciated!

Comment: P.S. In an answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185937/two-definitions-of-lebesgue-integration, for instance, the limit is only taken as $ b \to \infty $ and $ a $ is set equal to $ 0 $. Why don't we need to worry about $ F_f(t) $ not necessarily being finite at $ t = 0 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One can understand the right side as an improper Riemann integral if desired, in which case you would indeed use this formalism. But if you used the 1D Lebesgue integral to define the right side as well, then $F_f(0)=\infty$ is not a problem.
2. It's an integral of a nonnegative function, so it is a monotone function of $a,b$ (decreasing with $a$, increasing with $b$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Regarding (1.), equation (1) in the question is the definition of the Lebesgue integral in terms of Riemann integral, so we really have no choice but to understand the right side as an improper Riemann integral, right? Otherwise, could you elaborate on what you had in mind?

Comment: @Apollo13 The left side is an integral over a basically arbitrary measure space (it doesn't really need to be $\mathbb{R}^n$, nothing changes if it is an abstract measure space). The right side is an integral on just the real line. So you have more structure available to define the right side. If you want, you could use an improper Riemann integral to define the right side.

Comment: @Apollo13 (Cont.) You could alternately define the Lebesgue integral on just the real line by some other method and then use that to extend the definition to the general case, if you wanted. In general most authors prefer to use a different definition of the Lebesgue integral than that one because it is awkward to prove theorems using that definition.

Comment: Many thanks, that was very helpful! May I ask what another definition would look like? Could you perhaps refer me to a textbook that shows such an alternative approach to defining the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @Apollo13 Most of them, really, I like Royden/Fitzpatrick.

Answer (score 0):

The Lebesgue integral of a function is defined over all of the space and is then limited to intervals by
$$\int_a^b f := \int \chi_{(a,b)} f$$

Thus,
$$\int_0^\infty F_f(t) \, dt = \int \chi_{(0,\infty)} F_f(t) \, dt$$